# How to Kill a task in deadlock situaltion

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I am working with Tasks in C#. I have a situation to run my code in Task. But sometime that code can go to deadlock condition due to some algorithm issues. 
I am trying to achieve a waiting mechanism in such a way that

-I will start a task
-Wait for some times to finish Task execution
-If the task is not executed in a particular time, I will kill that task

This is I need to achieve. Sample code is given below.

The issue is even if i cancel the Task, it is executing without exit. Can someone help in this?

````
    public static class MyTest
    {
        public static void StartTask()
        {
            CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;
            Task task = new Task(() => TaskMethod(), token);

            task.Start();

            if (!task.Wait(1000))
            {
                tokenSource.Cancel();
                Console.WriteLine("Cancelled");

            }
        }


        public static void TaskMethod()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);

                Console.WriteLine("Haiiiiiii");
            }
        }

    }```
````

Comment: Try to avoid killing tasks. It will result in undefined behavior. If you could tell more about why it will result in a deadlock, we could think with you to avoid having a deadlock at all

Comment: If you have a real deadlock situation, then the most correct thing you can do is to isolate the broken code out into its own process, and then when you detect the deadlock situation, terminate the process. There is no good way to forcibly terminate tasks, and though there are methods for terminating threads, they're not meant for user code to be used, so you shouldn't. The correct way is to write cooperative cancellation into your tasks, but this is probably useless in a deadlock situation, and if you can't fix the deadlock bug, isolate the code so you can kill it.

Comment: And cancelling a task does not terminate the code execution, it simply signals that the task should be cancelled. In some cases, like if the task hasn't even been scheduled to run yet, it may be cancelled by the framework, but if it has started executing, and certainly if it is stopped at a deadlock, cancelling the task will do nothing. Cancelling is part of the cooperative cancellation concept I wrote about in my other comment, and the task code is supposed to check if it has been cancelled using a cancellation token, and then return/terminate if it has.

Answer (score 0):

`TaskMethod()` must return `Task`, and instead of `Thread.Sleep()` use `await Task.Delay()`, in this case `TaskMethod()` must be marked `async`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not a deadlock. Your task will never respond to the cancellation request.

The task isn't terminated by magic, you should check the `IsCancellationRequested` property of the `CancellationTokenSource`, change it from a local variable to a field, so your TaskMethod is able to access it.

Try this:

```
public static class MyTest
{
    CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public static void StartTask()
    {
        CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;

        // Use Task.Run
        Task task = Task.Run(() => TaskMethod(), token);

        if (!task.Wait(1000))
        {
            tokenSource.Cancel();
            Console.WriteLine("Cancelled");

        }
    }


    public static void TaskMethod()
    {
        while (!tokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        // -----------------^^
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            // optional check:
            if(!tokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                Console.WriteLine("Haiiiiiii");
        }
    }

}
```